# функция которая возвращает разряды числа

Tags: javascript

хотел сделать задачу но что-то застопорился:
Cоздать функцию которая принимает число и возвращает  текст как в примере:
3275  —>  "3000 + 200 + 70 +5"*/

```
   const func=(number)=>{
    let arr=number.toString().split("").reverse();
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i]=arr[i]*Math.pow(10,i);
    }
    let result=arr.reverse().join(" + ");
    console.log(result);
}
let number=32752;
func(number);
```

как надо было сделать, чтобы 2 раза не делать reverse?

Comment: Тут нужен цикл.

Comment: а что он будет делать

Comment: умножать число на 10, 100, 1000 и т.д., т.е. на 10^i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function foo(value) {
  return [...value.toString()]
    .map((v, i, a) => v.padEnd(a.length - i, "0")).join(' + ')
}

console.log(foo(3275))
```

- Разбиваем строку в массив `[...value.toString()]`
- Удлиняем каждый элемент до необходимого разряда `padEnd()`.
  Подсчитать очень просто: вся длина строки минус текущий индекс
  К примеру двойка -> "1234" -> `4 - 1`, значит `padEnd(3, "0") -> 200`
- Склеиваем `.join(' + ')`

UPD: При необходимости исключить нули, лучше так

```js
function foo(value) {
  return [...value.toString()]
    .map((v, i, a) => (+v ? v.padEnd(a.length - i, "0") : false)).filter((v) => v).join(' + ')
}
console.log(foo(3075))
```

Comment: стоит добавить пояснение как это работает

Comment: @Grundy я еще там и опечатался, в `padEnd(..., 0)` номер вставил, но сработал